# Facebook android SDK login action

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new to Facebook SDK.
So as far as I read from their tutorial, when you use custom button with their loginManager, it starts an intent of webview or the native FB app to ensure the login.
So my question, is there a way to make it custom ? like using edittext of android to get the username/password then  start the login session.

Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that for security reasons. With the facebook sdk, your app open a webview or the facebook app if the user already has installed.

If you want to save some user data, you have to set the proper permissions and you can get it with the user token and the facebook graph api.

Regards!!

Comment: thank you for your reply, So you're saying there is no way to do that ...huh? :)

Comment: Exactly, it's not possible.